# Fill Condition: Possible?

Tags: pine-script

I'm unable to use a fill() inside an if statement, so I attempted to use a fill condition but it keeps failing. looking for some assistance on the best way to pass the data I need in.

```
//Attempt 1
if ema25 > H3
    if ema25 < H4
        var ema25fill = pH3, ema25plot, title = "EMA Zone", color = color.yellow, transp = 50


fill(pH3, ema25plot, title = "EMA Zone", color = color.yellow, transp = 50)
```

```
//Attempt 2
var ema25fill = true
fill(ema25fill ? pH3, ema25plot : na, title = "EMA Zone", color = color.yellow, transp = 50)
```

```
//Attempt 3
if ema25 > H3
    if ema25 < H4
        var ema25fill = true
    fill(pH3, ema25plot, title = "EMA Zone", color = color.yellow, transp = 50)
```

I tried a few other ways; none seem to work best. Any help here would be wonderful.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

fill(pH3, ema25plot, title = "EMA Zone", color = ema25fill ? color.yellow : na, transp = 50)

Just ended up doing a color condition instead of an if statement.